# microsoft graph api onenote copy pages no longer working?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onenote

Until beginning of April I was able to copy OneNote pages from one certain section of a notebook to another section of another notebook without problems.
Suddenly just the copy function ceased working.

What I do in detail (with the correct ids of course):

I do a GET in graph api explorer
[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/{groupid}/onenote/notebooks/{section}/sections](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/%7Bgroupid%7D/onenote/notebooks/%7Bsection%7D/sections)
to get the section id .
Then a POST [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{groupid}/onenote/pages/{pageid}/copyToSection](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/%7Bgroupid%7D/onenote/pages/%7Bpageid%7D/copyToSection)
In the body I have {"id": "{section id from GET above}","groupId": "{groupid as above}"} .
Executing this post does not give me an error at all but the page does not show in the  concerned section.

Does anybody experience the same problems with the MS Graph Api?

Mirko

Comment: Does it return 202 response code with Operation-Location header? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/section-copytosectiongroup?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#response

Comment: Yes it does. I reacts as if everything is okay.

Comment: I had the same issue. Posted a report at microsoft graph explorer GitHub page as it also wasn't working https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-explorer-v4/issues/2521 and at learn Microsoft https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1251761/graph-api-nd-onenote-api-copytosection-endpoint-no and the issue was identified and appears resolved.